# Is there a way to pretty print an JavaScript file in Safari 6.0 Web Inspector?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

Dose anyone know how to pretty print a JavaScript file in Safari 6.0 Web Inspector?

Comment: Open Web Inspector -> Go to Scripts -> Open desired Script -> Click pretty print brackets in the bottom

Comment: Seems to be missing in 6.0.2. Not sure when it went away or where it went.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's documentation on the Safari Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/ResourcesandtheDOM/ResourcesandtheDOM.html) says the button with braces on it will do what you want (@AurA mentioned this in the comments).

The documentation says this under **Resources and the DOM ▸ Resources and Storage ▸ JavaScript and CSS**.